# Maven uses wrong repository to lookup dependencies

Tags: maven, repository

In my `settings.xml` I declared a custom repository in a profile like this:

```
    <servers>
    <server>
        <id>server.id</id>
        <username><uname></username>
        <password><pw></password>
    </server>
</servers>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev.id</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>repo.id</id>
                <url>valid working url</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

what works great for all dependencies located there, but build fails whenever I declare dependencies which are located in the central repository. For instance:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

results in:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <name>: Could not resolve dependencies for project…
…Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit-dep:jar:4.9.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit-dep:pom:4.9.1-SNAPSHOT from/to <server.id>…
```

How can I make maven load dependencies correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a -SNAPSHOT dependency which is not available in Maven Central.

```
junit:junit-dep:jar:4.9.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit-dep:pom:4.9.1-SNAPSHOT fr
```

In Maven central there are only releases available.

Furthermore the above dependency is not coming into your build by the junit:junit:4.11:jar dependency it must be comming from other sources.

Comment: After changing the <activatedByDefault> to false, the junit dependency was included correctly, but not the ones from my repository.